# find the coordinates of the vector $(a,b,c)?$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Suppose $a_1 = (1,0,-i) $ , $a_2 =(1+i , 1-i,1)$ , $a_3 =(i,i,i)$ in $\mathbb{C}^3$ . What are the coordinates  of the vector $(a,b,c)$ in this basis ?

**My attempt** : Here obviously $a_1,a_2$ and $a_3$  will form  basis since  det $A \neq 0$

take $A=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 &   0   & -i \\
    1+i & 1-i & 1  \\
    i &   i & i
\end{bmatrix}$

and  we have  $$A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1-2i}{5} &   \frac{1-2i}{5}   &  \frac{3-i}{5}\\
     \frac{1-2i}{5}& \frac{1+3i}{5} & \frac{-2-i}{5}  \\
    \frac{-2+4i}{5} & \frac{-2-i}{5}   & \frac{-1-3i}{5} 
\end{bmatrix}$$

The coordinates  of the vector $(a,b,c)$ in this basis =$A^{-1}  \begin{bmatrix}  a \\ b\\c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1-2i}{5}a +   \frac{1-2i}{5}b   +  \frac{3-i}{5}c\\
     \frac{1-2i}{5}a+\frac{1+3i}{5}b + \frac{-2-i}{5} c \\
    \frac{-2+4i}{5}a + \frac{-2-i}{5} b + \frac{-1-3i}{5}c 
\end{bmatrix}$

Is my solution  is correct or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't. Take the vector $(1,0,-i)$ for example. Then you get

$$A^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
-i
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-i\\
0\\
-1+i
\end{bmatrix}$$

But $(1,0,-i)$ is the first element of your basis so you should be getting $(1,0,0)$.

To see where you went wrong, look at how you constructed your change of basis matrix $A$.

If $A^{-1}$ takes a vector written in the canonical basis and gives you the vector written in the $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ basis, $A$ should do the opposite. Then what should you get for
$$A \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}?$$
Notice that this tells you what $A$'s first column should be.

Answer (score 0):

From Paulo answer

i notice  that  to find the coordinate

$$A^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
-i
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$

must satisfied

Therefore the  coordinates  of the vector $(a,b,c)$ in this basis =$(A^{-1})^T  \begin{bmatrix}  a \\ b\\c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1-2i}{5}a +   \frac{1-2i}{5}b   +  \frac{-2+4i}{5}c\\
     \frac{1-2i}{5}a+\frac{1+3i}{5}b + \frac{-2-i}{5} c \\
    \frac{3-i}{5}a + \frac{-2-i}{5} b + \frac{-1-3i}{5}c 
\end{bmatrix}$